# How to delete a document on mongodb(mongoose) after X time since the DELETE call?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I http.delete(api, params, etc..), I don't wanna delete the document immediately, just schedule the deletion after x time depending on a param.

I was thinking to use setTimeout? is that a good way of doing that? what's the proper way to approach this thanks..

Comment: Yes, use setTimeout.

Comment: There's something called `TTL`, used to remove a document after a certain time. Check this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you  wanted to  delete  a  document at  fix  time after  insert /update   ,you  can  use a  ttl  index  ,when  use  ttl  index  the data will not be delete  immediately  ,but  if  the delete  time  is  not  fix  (may  related  to  your  param )   .  you can't  use the ttl index .

for the scond  case . you have to write a applicantion  to monitor the collection

compare  the  `data_time`  `delay_time`  `now`   then delete ,the better is with aggregation   .

what is  more  the `setTimeout()`  is  a good way to callback after a certain period of time .